# "Thing + of + its price" is a correct expression?

Tags: prepositions, usage

**Example 1**
[My car of 2000 dollars] runs very fast.

**Example 2**
Where did you get [your car of 1000 dollars]?

**Example 3**
[The car of 1000 dollars] over there looks nice.

**Example 4**
I want [this car of 1000 dollars].

---

**Question 1**

Are Examples 1-4 correct?

**Question 2**

Are the expressions in the brackets correct?

"Thing + of + its price" is a correct expression?

Answer (score 2):

It is not idiomatic.

It is possible to say "My two thousand dollar car", but in some of your examples it would be clearer to use a relative clause:

> The car over there that costs $1000 looks nice.

Your second example would be odd however you phrase it, It suggests that the person has several cars and you distinguish them by price.  But price is not a fixed properly of a car.  It would be more natural in most situations to say "Where did you get your red car" or "...your VW beetle"